# Get all items inside quotes in Cucumber Step Definition

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber, gherkin

I have a string: `I attach "dog.png", "cat.png", and "alphabet.doc"`

This is what I want matched:

```
1. dog.png
2. cat.png
3. alphabet.doc
```

I can do this by doing `"([^"]*)"`, however, the string has to start with 'I attach'

This is the current rule I have in my step definition: `/^I attach "([^"]*)"$/` but this doesn't work.

This is for cucumber/gherkin, I can figure something out using `scan` but I don't think you can use that in cuke/gherkin?

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't think you can use `scan`?

Comment: @pguardiario These rules are for step definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture a variable number of inputs in a single step, I think the best option is to use `scan`. While you cannot use scan directly in the step name, you can capture the full list of files and then parse the captured result.

Try the following step definition:

```
Given /^I attach (.*)$/ do |file_list|
  files = file_list.scan(/"(.+?)"/).flatten
  #=> ["dog.png", "cat.png", "alphabet.doc"]
end
```

This will create an array of files to attach. It can handle 1 to infinite files.

Comment: This is great.  I was wondering how to use scan in this context.  I have had a similar need to the OP and this helps.  +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good place to use the #And alias.

```
Given I attach dog.png
  And I attach cat.png
  And I attach alphabet.doc
...
```

Alternatively you can use [data tables](http://docs.behat.org/guides/1.gherkin.html#tables) for easy multiline arguments